# SQLAlchemy Definir clase lista de otras

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Quiero definir una clase que contenga otras, pero sin ser una relación en sí.
No se si se puede utilizar el método relatioship pero sin claves o habría que hacerlo con queries, pero sin tener que pasarle la sesión.

¿Es posible hacer esto?

Gracias por vuestros comentarios!

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class Users():
    all = xxxxxx

    def get_all():
        return self.all

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    fullname = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)

    addresses = relationship("Address", backref="user", order_by="Address.id")

class Address(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(ForeignKey('user.id'))
    email_address = Column(String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la biblioteca que usas, podrías simplemente definir un metodo `all` dentro de users que haga la query a `all`:

Este es un ejemplo para `flask-sqlalchemy`

```
def User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    @classmethod
    def all(cls):
        return cls.query.all()
```

luego llamas:

```
from models import User

users = User.all()

for user in users:
    pass
    # ...
```

No tengo como comprobar esto ahora mismo, pero esa es la idea

EDIT:

Si solo usas sql-alchemy a secas, debería ser algo como:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

def User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

    @classmethod
    def all(cls, session): # este parametro es la session de sqlalchemy
        return session.query(cls, cls.name).all()
```

Luego llamas de la siguiente forma:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import User

some_engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost/')

Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)

session = Session()

lista = User.all(session)
```

Esa es la idea, espero ayude

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero no me funciona :(

(Pdb) User.all()
*** AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'query'

Por complementar:

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

Comment: @JoséManuel entiendo, por eso aclaré que depende de la biblioteca que uses. En tu caso deberías cambiar `cls.query` por tu session de sqlalchemy, mira este [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_basics.html#getting-a-session) para ver como instanciar una session. Mi ejemplo es para la biblioteca `flask-sqlalchemy`,  que agrega un atributo `query` a los modelos para consultar rápidamente. Mira este [link](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#querying-records) para mas información

Comment: Si, creo que voy a tener que mirar esa otra biblioteca. Vuelvo a darte las gracias por tu respuesta.